# Combine two lists with one different element

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark

I'm new in Scala and Spark and i don't know how to do this.

I have preprocessed a CSV file, resulting in an RDD that contains lists with this format:

```
List("2014-01-01T23:56:06.0", NaN, 1, NaN)
List("2014-01-01T23:56:06.0", NaN, NaN, 2)
```

**All lists have the same number of elements.**

What I want to do is to combine the lists having the same first element (the timestamp). For example, I want this two example lists to produce only one List, with the following values:

```
List("2014-01-01T23:56:06.0", NaN, 1, 2)
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: So you're looking to *group by* timestamp. Either you switch to dataframes and you can use `groupBy`, or you can stay with RDDs and use something like `rdd.map(list => list.head -> list.tail).reduceByKey(yourReduceFunc)`.

Comment: List should not be used in this way. List[Any] is useless.
You need a `case class A(datetime: String, a: Double, b : Double, c: Doule)` and a list of A `List[A]`. Which you could `groupBy(_.datetime)` and then reduce the right part of the results.

Answer (score 1):

```
    # Below can help you in achieving your target

    val input_rdd1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(("2014-01-01T23:56:06.0", "NaN", "1", "NaN")))
    val input_rdd2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(("2014-01-01T23:56:06.0", "NaN", "NaN", "2")))
    //added one more row for your data
    val input_rdd3 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(("2014-01-01T23:56:06.0", "2", "NaN", "NaN")))
    val input_df1 = input_rdd1.toDF("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")
    val input_df2 = input_rdd2.toDF("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")
    val input_df3 = input_rdd3.toDF("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")

    val output_df = input_df1.union(input_df2).union(input_df3).groupBy($"col1").agg(min($"col2").as("col2"), min($"col3").as("col3"), min($"col4").as("col4"))

    output_df.show

output:
+--------------------+----+----+----+
|                col1|col2|col3|col4|
+--------------------+----+----+----+
|2014-01-01T23:56:...|   2|   1|   2|
+--------------------+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

If array tail values are doubles, can be implemented in this way (as sachav suggests):

```
val original = sparkContext.parallelize(
  Seq(
    List("2014-01-01T23:56:06.0", NaN, 1.0, NaN),
    List("2014-01-01T23:56:06.0", NaN, NaN, 2.0)
  )
)

val result = original
  .map(v => v.head -> v.tail)
  .reduceByKey(
    (acc, curr) => acc.zip(curr).map({ case (left, right) => if (left.asInstanceOf[Double].isNaN) right else left }))
  .map(v => v._1 :: v._2)

result.foreach(println)
```

Output is:

```
List(2014-01-01T23:56:06.0, NaN, 1.0, 2.0)
```